# Skill bar is not loading on page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem with the skill bar, everything works fine in the local html index file, but after uploading the skill bar to the server, it stops loading as if there was no script, someone has an idea how to fix it, thank you for your time and help. I link my we to let you see what is the problem https://neqts.github.io/TomaszTopor/

```js
 
      $('.skill-per').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var per = $this.attr('per');
        $this.css("width",per+'%');
        $({animatedValue: 0}).animate({animatedValue: per},{
          duration: 1000,
          step: function(){
            $this.attr('per', Math.floor(this.animatedValue) + '%');
          },
          complete: function(){
            $this.attr('per', Math.floor(this.animatedValue) + '%');
          }
        });
      });
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.skills{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.skill-name{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.skill-bar{
  height: 20px;
  background: #cacaca;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.skill-per{
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #0fbcf9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 1s linear;
  position: relative;
}

.skill-per::before{
  content: attr(per);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: -35px;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.skill-per::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  top: -16px;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="skills">
      <div class="skill">
        <div class="skill-name">HTML</div>
        <div class="skill-bar">
          <div class="skill-per" per="90"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="skill">
        <div class="skill-name">CSS</div>
        <div class="skill-bar">
          <div class="skill-per" per="70"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="skill">
        <div class="skill-name">Javascript</div>
        <div class="skill-bar">
          <div class="skill-per" per="60"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There seems to be an error with jquery at your website. If you can check with Chrome devtools you will see the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):15

Comment: yes u are right

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are loading jquery from a non-secure connection.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

change it to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

Please see the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Yes i see holy molly i didnt know that  Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure could cruse all script

Comment: As your website is served over https, it won't be able to load any resources from http connections.